# Link to sources in a foreign language

Tags: support, hyperlinks, languages

When answering questions, I like to give credit to any source of information by adding a link to that source. However, since I'm Dutch a source might happen to be in Dutch as well. Most people won't be helped by a direct link but only by a short summary. Should I still include the link then?

What is the best way to give credit to sources in foreign languages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others said, you should write a summary, and provide the link anyway.
This is also in keeping with the "Attribution" requirement of the [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license that the StackExchange network uses.
The link should probably come with a warning that it refers to a non-English page (e.g. "link (in Dutch)").
By including the link, you give other people the chance to apply a translation service.

Comment: Following StackExchange policies is a good point. The quality of some automated translations could be the sole reason to adding a summary ;).

Answer (score 5):

Since most people will **not** be able to read the resource, you should provide at least a summary with the link.

If you can link to an additional resource in English, all the better.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with links is link rot, therefore you should write the relevant content (of course in English).

For the code (if it is pasted on a site like pastebin), the language is irrelevant, because only the comments are influenced by the language (comments are generally helpful, but not necessary).

Comment: (After your edit). Ok, in that sense it applies to any link, even ones to English sources. It's a bit off topic, but I think giving a synopsis of the relevant parts is usually good practice.